# Moving emails/messages using Microsoft Graph SDK's Batch Requests

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-mail

My objective is to process emails in a folder and then move them to another folder to which I have the id. To ease the workload I'm trying to make use of the batch functionality.

Unfortunately, every time I try to run the batch function I'm presented with an exception with the message `Code: invalidRequest Message: Unable to deserialize content.`.

The code in question, simplified for just one request, can be found below.

```cs
var batch = new BatchRequestContent();

var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize( new { destinationId =  Graph.Me.Messages[messageId].Move(folderId).Request().RequestBody.DestinationId } );
var jsonMessage = Graph.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeAsJsonContent(json);

var request = Graph.Me.Messages[messageId].Move(folderId).Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
request.Content = jsonMessage;

batch.AddBatchRequestStep(request);

var res = await Graph.Batch.Request().PostAsync(batch);
```

I've narrowed down the problem to be about the `request.Content` because without that it will go through, though getting back with a 400 error about missing body.

Copying the string from `batch.ReadAsStringAsync()` and pasting that directly into the Graph Explorer and using that to run the query returns a 200 success.

Based on what I've tried I'm starting to lean on it being a limitation of the SDK's batch.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

While this wasn't the solution I was looking for, it works as a band aid solution.

Basically, after you add all your steps to the `BatchRequestContent` you use the `ReadAsStringAsync()` to get the body of the request. Then you use the library itself to send the HTTP Request, as instructed [here](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/overview.md#send-http-requests-with-the-net-microsoft-graph-client-library).

```cs
HttpRequestMessage hrm = Graph.Batch.Request().GetHttpRequestMessage();
hrm.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
hrm.Content = Graph.HttpProvider.Serializer.SerializeAsJsonContent(await batch.ReadAsStringAsync());

// Authenticate (add access token) our HttpRequestMessage
await Graph.AuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateRequestAsync(hrm);

// Send the request and get the response.
HttpResponseMessage res = await Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(hrm);
```